# Is there a way to return an array of latitude and longitude coordinates using the google maps api?

Tags: arrays, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to pass an array of address to the google maps api, and then in return receive an array of longitude and latitude points. Is this possible? If so could I seen an example on how to construct the url to handle the array?

So it would be something like this:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false`

but i need to pass it `address` rather than `latlng`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a geocoder. Check out the Google docs here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder

and the code sample here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

You'll want to look at the `codeAddress()` function in the sample above. It should give you enough to get started :)