# How do I use Google Maps API in a Java code to fetch coordinates of specified location?

Tags: java, function, google-maps

In a BI project I'm currently working on, we are in need of geo-coordinates for a list of locations. With the address location (such as `"New York, US"`) as input, the output should be the coordinates as a latitude-longitude pair (like `{40.71435, -74.00597}`). The behaviour is similar to what is seen on [this](http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm) page.

A [similar question earlier on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293490/979621) points to using the Google Maps API in JavaScript to achieve this, but I'm looking for a Java solution -- some function of the form `getCoordinates(location)`, because this is a small requirement in a larger Java program already in existence.

Any pointers on how I may use the Google Maps API (or any other maps API) in Java to achieve this would be of great help!

Comment: why don't you use google javascript map API with Java ?? it will work fine .
i created entire project using that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Geocoding HTTP API (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)).
To connect to it and get the responses you can use a Java URLConnection (tutorial is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html)) and parse the response using your favourite Json library (I personally use Jackson)

Comment: Thanks! I found a tailor-made solution for _exactly_ what I was looking for – [GeocodingSample.java](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/geocoder/java/GeocodingSample.java?r=2476) (lucky me!). The program uses the same technique you've detailed.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like a way to perform Google Maps API Geocoding via Java - here's one that might work for you. The response might not be in the exact same format you need but should be pretty workable:

http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/

You can see the final format returned in LatLng.java - just trace the code through starting from GeocodeResponse.java and you'll see the final format - the classes are pretty simple.